# Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.IList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>'

Tags: c#, c#-10.0

Using C# 10 I am trying to convert an `IEnumerable<String>?` to an `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
IEnumerable<String>? inputs = getValues();

if (inputs is null)
  return false;

Type type = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T));

IList? outputs = (IList?)Activator.CreateInstance(type);

TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));

if (converter is null || outputs is null || !converter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(String)))
  return false;

foreach (String input in inputs) {
  if (converter.IsValid(input)) 
    outputs.Add(converter.ConvertFromString(input));
}

var texpression = new TExpression<T>(outputs);
```

I am getting an error on last line even if I use `outputs.ToList()`:

```
Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.IList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>'
```

The `TExpression` constructor is:

```
public TExpression(IEnumerable<T> values) { 
  Values = values;
}
```

I tried to change the types of my conversion code but I always end with an error somewhere.

How can I fix this so I can use the constructor without changing the constructor?

**Update**

Using the following:

```
IList<T> outputs = (IList<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
...
foreach (string input in inputs) {
  if (converter.IsValid(input)) 
    outputs.Add((T)converter.ConvertFromString(input));
}
```

I get the warning (I am using `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>`):

```
Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.
```

`T` can be a nullable type (Int32?) or a non nullable type (Int32).

I could change the code line to:

```
T? output = (T?)converter.ConvertFromString(input);
```

This fixes the warning but is it correct?

What if T is a non nullable type?

Comment: outputs is an IList and TExpression returns an IEnumerable.

Comment: IList of what? Cast using generic type.. `outputs = (IList<T>)…`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you actually now the type of collection you can use it:

```cs
IList<T> outputs = (IList<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
...
foreach (string input in inputs) {
    if (converter.IsValid(input)) 
        outputs.Add((T)converter.ConvertFromString(input)); // here also
}
```

Comment: I tried what you propose before but then I get a null warning which I am not sure what is the correct way to fix it because T can itself be nullable or not. I just added an update to my question.

Comment: @MiguelMoura I would say that nullability should be out of scope of this question, but yes, you can change the types accordingly (i.e. `IList<T?>? outputs`) and so on for the sake of the nullability analysis.